Why I am facing [Errno 32] Broken pipe when I start new process?
I am using confluent-kafka to process messages from kafka topic.
Here is the code template:
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def handle_records(records):
    for record in records:
        # extracted all details for each record. Hidden here.
        process = Process(
                        target=process_msg,
                        args=(
                            partition,
                            offset,
                            headers_dict,
                            msg_key,
                            msg,
                            shared_dict,
                        ),
                    )
        p.start()
        # I am joining this properly

def foo(shared_dict, partition_num):
    consumer = create_consumer()
    consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic, partition_num)]

    while True:
        # here I am consuming 2 messages each based on some calculation.

        records = consumer.consume(num_messages=2, timeout=1)
        if not records:
            continue
        handle_records(records)

def main(shared_dict):
    total_partitions = 8 # Calculated using kafka method. Directly written here
    total_processes = []

    for partition_num in range(total_partitions):
        p = Process(target=foo, args=(shared_dict, partition_num), deamon=False)
        p.start()
        total_processes.append(p)

    for p in total_processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    shared_dict = manager.dict()
    # Added some key-value pairs to shared_dict
    main(shared_dict)

Here I just gave the template code. The error I am facing is I am spawning 8 processes because of 8 partitions. And each process will spawn 2 processes because of number of records it consumed. My code was running fine for initial 30/40 minutes. Later I am facing Broken Pipe error when I start new process in handle_records.
Note: In handle_records method I am 'joining' the processes which got spawned after processing my message. And again I will spawn new process when I fetch/consumer new records from topic. It is an iterative process. I was able to do this for some records later I got Broken Pipe Error.
If my consumer doesn't get any messages for some 1hr I will close the consumer and join the processes which spawned in main function.
2024-07-17 10:34:41, 480, Process-2, handle_records, Exception raised in handle_records: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "kafka_main.py", line 2380, in handle_records
process.start ()
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
self. popen = self. Popen (self)
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
return default_context.get_context () . Process ._ Popen (process_obj)
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in Popen
return Popen (process_obj)
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in init
super (). _init_(process_obj)
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 16, in init
util. flush_std_streams ()
File "/dpap/public/data/PythonProgramFiles/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 439, in _flush_std_streams
sys.stderr. flush ()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


So if one of the apps you spawn prints to stderr, where should that data go? To a console? The same one that the parent app is running from?

Thankyou for the reply. yes to the console @Brannon
